# Ktor QUICK START HTTP API - ERROR Application - Unhandled: GET - /snippets

Tags: kotlin, jackson, ktor

i'm new to Ktor and i am currently using the [quick start](https://ktor.io/quickstart/guides/api.html) http api but i receive the error:

ERROR Application - Unhandled: GET - /snippets
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl cannot be cast to kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl (through reference chain: java.util.Collections$Singleton
Map["snippets"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

CODE:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.features.CallLogging
import io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.features.DefaultHeaders
import io.ktor.jackson.jackson
import io.ktor.request.receive
import io.ktor.response.respond
import io.ktor.response.respondText
import io.ktor.routing.Routing
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.post
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import java.util.*

data class Snippet(val text: String)

val snippets = Collections.synchronizedList(mutableListOf(
    Snippet("hello"),
    Snippet("world")
))

fun Application.main() {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        jackson {
            enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        }
    }
    routing {
        get("/snippets") {
            call.respond(mapOf("snippets" to synchronized(snippets) { snippets.toList() }))
        }
    }
}
```

If i use this instead:

```
 call.respond(mapOf("snippets" to synchronized(snippets) { snippets.toString() }))
```

it returns:

```
   {
  "snippets" : "[Snippet(text=hello), Snippet(text=world)]"
   }
```

but now it's using toString() rather than toList(), any idea how i can get it to work as in the quick start using toList()?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

using the watch option in the application.conf file to run the server seems to mess a couple things up.

application.conf file:

```
ktor {
    deployment {
        port = 8080
        watch = [ / ]
    }

    application {
        modules = [ com.MainKt.main ]
    }
}
```

removing

```
      watch = [ / ]
```

or switching back to the embedded server seems to have fixed the issue.

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {

         //rest of the code

    }.start(wait = true)
}
```